# How can I negate a search on a list using this iterable function?

Tags: python, iterator

I wrote a python function to search through an iterable:

```
def iter_search(iterable, **search):
    for item in iterable:
        # Assume we will find something to yield
        yield_me=True

        # Cycle through keys that exist in the search and item
        for key in item.viewkeys() & search:
            if item[key] is not None:
                if item[key] != search[key]:
                    # Key didn't match, don't yield this item
                    yield_me = False
        if yield_me:
            yield item
```

Works great, in that my search 'key' can be any number of dictionary key value pairs:

```
new_iterable = iter_search(iter, ** { 'C' : 'US', 'Sex' : 'm' })
```

Now, I'm trying to negate a search, so I tried:

```
def iter_search(iterable, **search):
    for item in iterable:
        yield_me=True
        for key in item.viewkeys() & search:
            if item[key] is not None:
                if search[key][0] == '!':
                    if item[key] == search[key][1:]:
                        yield_me = False
                else:
                    if item[key] != search[key]:
                        yield_me = False
        if yield_me:
            yield item
```

But now, it yields nothing when I include the my negation character ('!'):

```
    new_iterable = iter_search(iter, ** { 'C' : '!US', 'Sex' : 'm' })
```

I'm missing something simple.  What?

***EDIT*** I was testing the wrong version of my code!  The above works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your first search function could be simplified to:

```
def iter_search(iterable, **search):
    for item in iterable:
        # Cycle through keys that exist in the search and item
        if len(search.viewitems() & item.viewitems()) == len(search):
            yield item
```

e.g. if all *items* (key, value pairs) in `search` are matched against the item items there is a match and you can `yield`.

A quick demo that this works:

```
>>> demo = [
...     {'C': 'US', 'Sex': 'f', 'Age': 31},
...     {'C': 'US', 'Sex': 'm', 'Age': 42},
...     {'C': 'UK', 'Sex': 'm', 'Age': 24},
...     {'C': 'UK', 'Sex': 'f', 'Age': 50},
... ]
>>> list(iter_search(demo, C='US', Sex='m'))
[{'C': 'US', 'Age': 42, 'Sex': 'm'}]
```

Using negative search can then be:

```
def iter_search(iterable, **search):
    positive = {k: v for k, v in search.iteritems() if v[:1] != '!'}
    negative = {k: v[1:] for k, v in search.viewitems() - positive.viewitems()}
    for item in iterable:
        # Cycle through keys that exist in the search and item
        if len(positive.viewitems() & item.viewitems()) == len(positive):
            if not negative.viewitems() & item.viewitems():
                yield item
```

So there is an exact match on the positive search, and none of the negative items match.

Demo against the same inputs defined before:

```
>>> list(iter_search(demo, C='!US', Sex='m'))
[{'C': 'UK', 'Age': 24, 'Sex': 'm'}]
```

Comment: Haha ... I'll wait 5 minutes ... you keep making edits!

Comment: @Jamie: Yeah, as I build a demo I discover small mistakes; done now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I get you correctly but from what I understand, this might answer what you are looking for -

```
def iter_search(iterable, **search):
    for item in iterable:
        yield_me=False
        for key in item.viewkeys() & search:
            if item[key] is not None:
                if search[key][0] == '!':
                    if item[key] == search[key][1:]:
                        yield_me = True
        if yield_me:
            yield item
```

Comment: Not quite.  A single, negated field results in matching, regardless of any other fields not matching. And any non-negated searches don't match at all.